# libgit2sharp create pull request

Tags: c#, .net, pull-request, libgit2sharp

.NET 4.0 C#

Using libgit2sharp, I've written code to create a new branch, change some files, push branch to GitHub.

Now I need to create a pull-request. However, my Google searches don't turn up any relevant info.

Does libgit2sharp support creating PRs ?  If not, what are other options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does libgit2sharp support creating PRs ?

No it doesn't. A *"Pull Request"* (with comments, a neat Merge button...) is a concept that rather belongs to a git repository web hoster (eg. GitHub, BitBucket, ...).

> If not, what are other options ?

Git hosters expose Http APIs that allow you to do this programmatically:

- **Github:** **[Create a Pull Request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request)** (an its official .Net binding, **[Octokit.Net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net#octokit---github-api-client-library-for-net-)**)
- **BitBucket:** **[Create a Pull Request](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/pullrequests+Resource#pullrequestsResource-POST(create)anewpullrequest)**

Comment: thanks nulltoken - need i supply api-key or username/password credentials in the headers ?

Comment: For GitHub, IIRC, the username and token are expected

Comment: how to include username/token in headers ?

Comment: "how to include username/token in headers" -> I think this may deserve a question of its own ;-)

Comment: ok i figured-out how to send token but response is 403 Forbidden indicating authentication succeeded but authorization failed which is strange because same GitHub user can create PR manually - any ideas why it would fail via GitHub API ?

Comment: found out that all GitHub API requests require User-Agent but still get 403